# NotificationCenter observers prevent dealloc with ARC

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, nsnotificationcenter

I am trying to debug a project which I have recently converted to use ARC.
I am having a hard time determining why objects are not released and stay in memory (is there an easy way to see what reference keeps an object in memory?)

One problem seems with notification centre links.
On viewDidLoad I register three notifications:

```
[notificationCenter addObserverForName: kAudioPlaybackStart
                                object: nil
                                 queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                            usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                                [self handle_PlaybackStateStart:nil];
                            }];
[notificationCenter addObserverForName: kAudioPlaybackStop
                                object: nil
                                 queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                            usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                                [self handle_PlaybackStateStop:nil];
                            }];
[notificationCenter addObserverForName: kAudioPlaybackPause
                                object: nil
                                 queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                            usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                                [self handle_PlaybackStatePause:nil];
                            }];
```

Then, when the viewController is done I call a function unLoad:

```
- (void) unLoad {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

    _mediaPlayerHelper = nil;
    _article = nil;
    _tableView = nil;
}
```

The reason I have a separate function is that viewDidUnload is not called unless all objects are released, so I need something to release them. Currently I call them on viewDidDisappear.

However, the code works fine (and view unloads) when commenting out the observers, but with the observers it doesn't seem to work and the view stays in memory. Any suggestions?

Comment: in your block you have referenced [self handle..], which will trigger a retain cycle. I think it would be better to remove oberserver with thier names. check that with instruments allocation template.

Comment: Is there a way to see which reference is holding the object? It says '1', but I cannot find an easy way to find out where the '1' is coming from.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are using the notification methods which take a block argument and you use a strong reference to `self` in the block. You should use the observation method which uses a callback selector (so there is no capture) or create a `__weak` reference to `self` to use in the blocks.

Comment: Thanks Wain, that was a useful hint. When switching to ARC I should have done a bit more background study on the ins-and-outs!

Answer (score 1):

You're not removing your observers when calling

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

You have to pass not `self`, but return values of `addObserverForName:...` methods.

Something like this. For all of the observers.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) id audioStartObserver;

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.audioStartObserver = [notificationCenter addObserverForName: kAudioPlaybackStart
                            object: nil
                             queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                        usingBlock:^(NSNotification *note) {
                            [self handle_PlaybackStateStart:nil];
                        }];
     // ...
 }

- (void) unLoad {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self.audioStartObserver];
    self.audioStartObserver = nil;

     // ...
}
```

Using weak reference to self will not remove the observer. This will just allow to dealloc your view controller. But observer blocks will still be in notification center. And they will be called each time.